# Compare two Objects in a list using lambda in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, arraylist

I think I can do this on my own with maybe 20 lines of code. But i think it can be a one-liner.

Lets say we have a list of cars with 1,2 or 3 wheels.

Cars[ ] = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6]

C1-C3 has only one wheel, C4 two, and C5-C6 three.

```
class Car{
   constructor(wheels){
      this.wheels = wheels;
   }
}
```

I want this result:

> *FilteredCars[ ] = [[C1,C2,C3],[C4],[C5,C6]]*

**or**

> FilteredCars[ ] = [[C1,C2,C3], [C5,C6]

=> i need the information which objects have the same value in "wheels"

**wheels are strings in my project with possible 48 different values, so i need the comparison carX === carY**

My "try" is like ("pseudoCode"):

```
Cars.filter(carx => 
   FilteredCars.add(Cars.filter (cary => 
      carx.wheels === cary.wheels).toList()));
         .
```

Comment: how could I know *C1-C3 has only one wheel, C4 two, and C5-C6 three*, is CX an object?

Comment: @hgb123 yes, sry forget to give the class. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you group cars by number of wheels, and then grab the cars on each group

You could do it in one line like this

```js
let id = 0;

class Car {
  constructor(wheels) {
    this.id = ++id;
    this.wheels = wheels;
  }
}

const data = [
  new Car("1"),
  new Car("1"),
  new Car("1"),
  new Car("2"),
  new Car("3"),
  new Car("3"),
];

const res = [...data.reduce((acc, el) => acc.set(el.wheels, [...(acc.get(el.wheels) || []), el]), new Map()).values()];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks vm! ill try to adapt this to my project. Could you maybe explain what happens in this line. I want to understand this :). "el" is the car u iterate. But what is "acc"? And where is the logic, where you group by number of wheels?

Comment: @psclp `acc` is the accumulated value, here initialized with a Map, with each loop, the Map will be filled with appropriated value, you could regard the simpler sum calculation example with reduce: `arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0)`

Comment: does it mean it works only if wheels is an int right? 

in my project the "wheels" are strings. So i need the comparison carX === carY to filter.

Comment: nvm it works with strings too. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question. You can simply do

```
 const Cars = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6]
const FilteredCars =[Cars.filter(car=>car.wheels===1),Cars.filter(car=>car.wheels===2),Cars.filter(car=>car.wheels===3)]
```

You will get  [[C1,C2,C3],[C4],[C5,C6]] this kind of result

Comment: In my project Cars.wheels have more than 3 different values. It would be a long one-liner if i filter by different values :D.